# Администрирование

Tags: администрирование

В организации от 70 компов. Какие трудности могут возникнуть в администрировании? Есть ли советы бывалых?

Comment: Как то размыто, вы просите совет/ответ на проблему до того как что-то случится.  
Это же ПК, может случится что угодно, от поломки подставки кофе (CD-ROM), до настройки принтера через Wi-Fi для нескольких ОС.

Comment: Скорее совет. Я в администрировании новичок. Чем можно воспользоваться в трудную минуту? (справка - не ответ)

Comment: @new_russian_man командой `ping`

Answer (score 3):

Идеал, если есть более опытный админ в штате и если критическая ситуация, то к нему бежать. Ну, а так регистрируйтесь на форумах для админов, подборку блоггеров собирайте себе в РСС ленту, джаббер - найдите админов, можно несколько, чтобы было куда в реальном времени обратиться, ну, и конечно же Гугл, без него никуда.

И напоследок, если вы на Win сидите, то пора вам с неё слезть и полностью перейти и дома, и на работе на Linux.

Comment: А для начала что можно почитать? На пример ситуация такая - комп вне сети. Что делать?
1. Проверить подключение
2. Кабели
Что еще может быть причиной?

Comment: Сложно сказать именно что читать. Каждая книга ориентирована на какой-то уровень задач, нет такой книги в которой будут все ответы, даже Гугл не на всё ответит. По практике могу сказать что читайте внимательно ошибки, они везде довольно информационные, не отвергайте руководства и возможными системными подсказками решения проблем, обычно разработчики ПО предполагают о возможных ошибках и всё решается без колдовства.  
ИМХО лучше какие-то справочники искать, а вообще всё приходит с опытом, и решение частной проблемы по большей части также частно и решается.

Comment: Везде Линукс и предполагается вводить (

Comment: И напоследок - было субъективное мнение, я ни в коем случае не навязываю. И если у нашего героя Win-сеть, то я не могу сказать что ему чертовски повезло, но даже если Win то все мои предыдущие советы всё равно актуальны.

Comment: @new_russian_man что собственно и стоило ожидать. Не расстраивайтесь, дальше будет легче.

Comment: Спасибо. Но неужели сеть линекса это так ужасно? просто 70 компов это вроде не мало.....

Comment: Ну для новичка не легко, и главное непривычно очень, но с практикой будет все понятно как 2+2. А овладев Linux там и ворота будут много куда открыты, да и для себя будет полезно/позновательно.

Comment: Субъективное кто же спорит. Но приведенное вне всякого контекста оно выглядит странно

Comment: Конечно, когда планируется внедрение *никса, первый совет trec'a просто констатация факта (совет - только в переходе на *никс дома). Приведу пример - в нашей организации несколько десятков филиалов. Все - под виндой. Почему? Потому что 1. Сеть организована давно, и заново ее перепроектировать и переустановить на все машины *никс - обойдется в неплохую такую "копеечку", 2. организация разработала и продолжает разрабатывать программные инструменты для персонала. последнее время появились веб-приложения, но до сих пор - только виндовые. Таким образом, на данный момент переход - не реален...

Comment: Комп не в сети... Что значит "не в сети"? Лампочка есть? горит? Что говорит ifconfig (или ipconfig) Up? Адреса/маски подсети совпадают? И т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Главный совет - запасись терпением.
В администрировании самая главная проблема - люди. С ними нужно тактично и с пониманием того, что это не специалисты. Ты не знаешь бухгалтерию, а бухгалтер плавает в компьютерах. Так и должно быть. Если с улыбкой и терпением, то тебе простят даже некоторую некомпетентность.
А технические проблемы всегда можно решить поискав в гугле или задав вопрос.

Comment: Хотя насчет наивности пользователей в компутерах -- в наше время всякое может быть. Вполне возможно и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве совета начинающему админу - узнайте, какой дистрибутив Linux будет использоваться в вашей фирме. Установите его у себя дома - это будет первый опыт. Если боитесь, - поставьте для начала на виртуальную машину - последние версии бесплатного Vmware Player позволяют создавать виртуальные машины любых конфигураций. Потихоньку начинайте разбираться - настройте вновь установленную систему, разберитесь с помощью интернета во всех возникающих по ходу установки вопросах. И так далее... В добрый путь!

Comment: не-не-не, лучше ставиь на реальную, что если что-то случилось, то разгребать ручками, а не создавать новую вирт машину =)

Comment: @1101_debian боюсь, что в последнем случае возникнет соблазн "форматнуть все к такой-то матери" и поставить винды )))

Comment: Естественный отбор, епта =)

Comment: абсолютно согласен с @1101_debian, разбираться надо среальными проблемами а не виртуальными...хоть и будет соблазн все снести и поставить винду, но это будет тоже определенный гемор а значит опыт, а так закрыл виртуальную машину и вперед лазить по винде :)

Comment: Позволю себе высказать несогласие ).Если есть определенный опыт, и точно уверен в том, что делаешь, или, хотя-бы, есть еще один комп, подключенный к и-нету, на котором "если что" можно будет порыться в гугле, или есть товарищ, который может помочь в трудную минуту- тогда - пожалуйста. А вот когда ничего этого нет, то можно очень серьезно "попасть" с реальной системой.Помнится, был у меня такой случай, во времена, когда и-нет был только по диал-ап. Слетела система (вирус под 98 виндой), а под рукой ни системного диска, ни дискеты. Гемор был тот еще, пока я по нашему городку искал дистр Win98..

Comment: А ведь проблема была - весго-то переставить ОС... А если будет проблема с GRUB/LILO? Что делать? А если "случайно" при установке Linux снесли таблицу партиций и теперь нужно "в срочном порядке" восстанавливать потерянные семейные фото/файлы над которыми работал и т.д.? Так что, "в первый раз" лучше не рисковать... (хотя сам я, когда впервые ставил Linux (RedHat 7, кажется, может 5) - ставил на реальную систему... Тогда о VM я ничего не знал, да и комп у меня был Pentium 120 с 64MB RAM и 10 GB HDD...

Comment: Ну, и пускай снесет все фотки, файлы и все на свете. =)

Без реальной практики ковыряния проблем руками толку не будет никакого, никаких знаний не появится: запрос в гугл - "о, ага, вот оно" - копипаст - "ололо, работает".

Все!!! Ничего же не останется в голове, а при повторной проблеме человек опять полезет в гугл, вместо того, чтобы сделать все самому, может даже и лучше и быстрее...

З.Ы.

Linux на виртуальной машине первый шаг к резиновой женщине.

А Linux на реальной машине - второй шаг.

(c) bash

Answer (score -2):

Начинать работать нужно правильно.
Т.е. с обучения.
Есть учебные заведения осуществляющие подготовку специалистов. Именно специалистов, а не курсы по интернету "Как научиться управлять ИТ-структурой предприятия за 3 дня!"
Закон жизни: **Теория** + **Практика** = **Специалист**.

Comment: "сисОдмины" категорически не согласны с моим высказыванием. Такие люди никогда не любили учиться. _(В моём отделе, если даже такие и попадали в него, то долго не протягивали...)_